# git merging, I keep screwing it up.

Tags: git

I know this is all over git docs, and stack overflow, but I still cant seem to figure out what Im doing wrong.

I am working with git in attempt to do a hard revert to one of my commits. meaning that I want to discard all of my new commits since then, and re-publish all of the files (86 changes)

from branch master I have run

```
git checkout 6dde2c36b35e6a38b6528d4445b
git checkout -b iwantthesechanges
```

so now i am no longer in detached HEAD state, and I have two branches;

```
git branch
```

returns

```
master
*iwantthesechanges
```

so now from here how can I overwrite master with all of my old changes.

I have tried

```
git merge master iwantthesechanges
```

and

```
git merge iwantthesechanges master
```

and I'm back where I started.

Thanks for reading

Comment: You should do a pull request to merge in master from your `iwanttesechanges` branch. Otherwise, while you're checked in `iwantthesechanges` branch just do `git merge master`

Comment: while Im checked into `iwantthesechanges` branch, and I run `git merge master` git merges in the newest changes, i want to revert to old changes

Comment: `git merge` isn't the way to go for your use case, q.v. the helpful responses given below.

Comment: @RobBenz , sorry, while you're checked in `master` you should do `git merge iwantthesechanges` . But what @Tim said, is a better solution, a more appropiate one actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how merging work. All of the commits in `iwantthesechanges` are already in `master`, so when you try to merge master into `iwantthesechanges` you'll get "Already up to date", and when you try the other way around, `iwantthesechanges` will be brought up to date with master.

You want to

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard 6dde2c36b35e6a38b6528d4445b # brings master back to 6dde2
git push --force origin master #beware! You will rewrite history!
```

If you want to still have the changes you wish to discard somewhere, create a new branch on `master` before you `reset`.

Another, less aggressive option would be to use `git revert` to revert all of the changes since 6dde2c, (perhaps `rebase` them so that it's one big commit instead of 86 commit objects), and push that.

Read more:

- [`git reset`](http://devdocs.io/git/git-reset)
- [`git revert`](http://devdocs.io/git/git-revert)
- [`git rebase`](http://devdocs.io/git/git-rebase)

Comment: I get the feeling that @RobBenz wanted to do a `git revert` but someone though that merging was the way to go.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen to be fair, I would have gone with a revert + rebase in this  case. Less history loss.

Comment: You are right @Tim, merging was not the correct operation, I am new to git. lesson learned.

Answer (score 1):

Merging the `iwantthesechanges` branch into `master` won't overwrite `master`, it will only create a new commit on top of `master`.  If you want to roll `master` back to the `6dde2c36b35e6a38b6528d4445b` commit then you can just use this command:

```
git reset --hard 6dde2c36b3
git push -f origin 6dde2c36b3:master
```

This resets `master` to that earlier commit, then overwrites the remote `master` with the change.